# Generating file.el from file.org

Tags: org-mode, init-file

I have an init file called `settings.org` (using `#+BEGIN_SRC #+END_SRC` blocks for elisp code)

I would like to generate `settings.el` from it, so that I can load it inside `init.el` easily.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research this is the solution I managed to find:

Add `:tangle yes` to each block of code you want to export

```
\#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes
elisp code...
\#+END_SRC
```

Then inside the .org file use

```
M-x org-babel-tangle
```

This will create a file with the same name but with the `.el` extension.

In my case I generated `settings.el` and included it in `init.el`

This can be automated with `(org-babel-load-file)` to directly load the org file.

But I personally prefer the extra step, to make sure I know what I'm loading and when.

Comment: +1 for finding an answer to your own question. Might it help others to add some info about how you found it?

Comment: Thanks, at this point I closed all the browser tabs, so don't remember exact links. But for the most part reading up on `org-babel` and what it does helped solve the problem.

Comment: Exporting source code (tangling) is described in the manual http://orgmode.org/org.html#Extracting-source-code.